# Показ ошибки

Tags: jquery, ajax, php, запрос

Подскажите, как сделать так, чтобы при отправке ajax'ом запроса обработчику, выводился бы ответ в определенный блок с ошибкой под формой jquery 1.8.0? Подскажите, как это можно будет реализовать. Если возможно, подкиньте туториал. Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если Вы отсылаете Ajax-запрос через jQuery, то в отсылаемом массиве данных укажите функцию, которая будет срабатывать всякий раз, когда AJAX-запрос не удался:

```
$.ajax({
    // ...
    error: function (e, err_msg) {
        alert(err_msg);
    },
    // ...
})
```

Этот метод является "обратным" методу успеха - `success`